# How to generate insert query with PL / SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to generate insert scripts with PL / SQL but i cant find a way how to do this. We want to transfer data between two databases.

```
CUSTOMER TABLE

ID
CUSTOMER_NUMBER
CUSTOMERINFO_ID

FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMERINFO_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERINFO (ID)

CUSTOMERINFO TABLE

ID
CUSTOMER_NAME
CUSTOMER_SURNAME
```

We have sample data in tables and we know CUSTOMER_NUMBER and we want to generate 2 insert script like these:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (ID, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMERINFO_ID)
VALUES(1,12345,1);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERINFO (ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_SURNAME)
VALUES(1,'NAME','SURNAME');
```

Since i can't find a way that will generate it now, I proceed as follows. I use DBeaver as database administration tool.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_NUMBER = 12345;
```

Then right click the row => Generate SQL => INSERT

```
Generated SQL => INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (ID, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMERINFO_ID) VALUES(1,12345,1);

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERINFO WHERE ID = 1
```

Then right click the row => Generate SQL => INSERT

```
Generated SQL => INSERT INTO CUSTOMERINFO (ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_SURNAME) VALUES(1,'NAME','SURNAME');
```

Now I have a script like below. I process the output here as in the above process.

```
DECLARE 
lv_customerNo varchar2(20):=:customerNumber;
lv_customer CUSTOMER%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO lv_customer FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_NUMBER = lv_customerNo ;
dbms_output.put_line('SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER bp WHERE ID =' || lv_customer.ID);
dbms_output.put_line('SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERINFO WHERE ID =' || lv_customer.CUSTOMERINFO_ID);
END;
```

I want to generate and print insert scripts with full data instead of these:

```
dbms_output.put_line('SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER bp WHERE ID =' || lv_customer.ID);
dbms_output.put_line('SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERINFO WHERE ID =' || lv_customer.CUSTOMERINFO_ID);
```

I explained this through 2 sample tables and a few columns, but our tables and columns are much more than that. So I want to prepare a PL / SQL script to automate this. But I couldn't find anything similar to this on the internet. How can i generate insert query with PL / SQL ?

Comment: I've just posted the updated answer that might help....@Onur

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to need to dynamically generate the code and then manually run it in a two-step process.

Instead, you can use sequences to generate the identifiers:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE customer__id__seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE customer_info__id__seq;
```

Then if you know `customer_number`, `customer_name` and `customer_surname` you can use a PL/SQL block to perform the inserts with the next sequence values:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_customer_number CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUMBER%TYPE       := 12345;
  v_first_name      CUSTOMERINFO.CUSTOMER_NAME%TYPE    := 'NAME';
  v_last_name       CUSTOMERINFO.CUSTOMER_SURNAME%TYPE := 'SURNAME';
  v_customer_id     CUSTOMERINFO.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- insert into customer_info first.
  INSERT INTO customerinfo (id, customer_name, customer_surname)
  VALUES (customer_info__id__seq.NEXTVAL, v_first_name, v_last_name)
  RETURNING id INTO v_customer_id;

  -- Then insert into customer as it has a foreign key to customer_info.
  INSERT INTO customer (id, customer_number, customerinfo_id)
  VALUES (customer__id__seq.NEXTVAL, v_customer_number, v_customer_id);
END;
/
```

If you want to perform this with multiple customer number/name/surname tuples then you could create a cursor or collections with the values and loop over that:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_customer_id     CUSTOMERINFO.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (
    SELECT 12345 AS customer_number, 'NAME' AS name, 'SURNAME' AS surname FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 23456, 'NAME1', 'SURNAME1' FROM DUAL
  )
  LOOP
    -- insert into customer_info first.
    INSERT INTO customerinfo (id, customer_name, customer_surname)
    VALUES (customer_info__id__seq.NEXTVAL, i.name, i.surname)
    RETURNING id INTO v_customer_id;

    -- Then insert into customer as it has a foreign key to customer_info.
    INSERT INTO customer (id, customer_number, customerinfo_id)
    VALUES (customer__id__seq.NEXTVAL, i.customer_number, v_customer_id);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WhWRWz5H)

---

#### Update

> I need insert scripts as text for transfer to another database.

This seems like an XY-problem and rather than manually trying to generate `INSERT` statements you can use the export data-pump `expdp` utility to backup the database (or individual tables) and then import them to the other database.

Comment: Actually that's not what i need. There are too many tables and too many columns for me to define manually . I need insert scripts as text for transfer to another database. I need a pl/sql query that will start with just one parameter then self-collecting all the remaining information with queries and generate insert scripts for all related tables. Start with just customerNumber and let it do everything else automatically, go to the tables and get the values ​​(Already ok so far). But I can't create the insert scripts to. I think i need something like a function or a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**
Made some adjustments to get closer to your needs.
Let's say that you have 2 tables with a foreign key relation like this:

```sql
--------------------------------------------------------
--  **Table A_TBL_2**

CREATE TABLE "A_TBL_2" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "CUSTOMER_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CUSTOMER_SURNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   );
CONSTRAINT "A_TBL_2_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
--
Select * From A_TBL_2;
        ID CUSTOMER_NAME        CUSTOMER_SURNAME   
---------- -------------------- --------------------
       111 NAME 1               SURNAME 1            
       222 NAME 2               SURNAME 2            
       333 NAME 3               SURNAME 3         

--------------------------------------------------------
--  **Table A_TBL_1**

CREATE TABLE "A_TBL_1" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
      "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
      "CUSTOMER_INFO_ID" NUMBER
   ) ;
CONSTRAINT "A_TBL_1_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("CUSTOMER_INFO_ID")
      REFERENCES "A_TBL_2" ("ID");

Select * From A_TBL_1;
        ID CUSTOMER_NUMBER CUSTOMER_INFO_ID
---------- --------------- ----------------
         1           12345              111 
         2           12345              222
```

... and that with call like below you can get both SELECT and INSERT sql commands passing just the table name
with Foreign Key created (A_TBL_1), the Column name (CUSTOMER_NUMBER) from that table and its value (12345) as a filter and either 'INSERT' (default)
or 'SELECT' as a type of resulting sql commands...

```sql
--  I N S E R T ---------------------
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    m_status VarChar2(2000) := '';
Begin
    m_status := SCRIPTS.Get_Scripts('A_TBL_1', 'CUSTOMER_NUMBER', 12345, 'INSERT');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(m_status);
End;

--  R e s u l t :
INSERT INTO A_TBL_2 (ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_SURNAME) VALUES(111, 'NAME 1', 'SURNAME 1');
INSERT INTO A_TBL_2 (ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_SURNAME) VALUES(222, 'NAME 2', 'SURNAME 2');
INSERT INTO A_TBL_1 (ID, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_INFO_ID) VALUES(1, 12345, 111);
INSERT INTO A_TBL_1 (ID, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_INFO_ID) VALUES(2, 12345, 222);
```

...  or  ...

```sql
--  S E L E C T ---------------------
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    m_status VarChar2(2000) := '';
Begin
    m_status := SCRIPTS.Get_Scripts('A_TBL_1', 'CUSTOMER_NUMBER', 12345, 'SELECT');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(m_status);
End;

--  R e s u l t :
Select ID, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_INFO_ID From A_TBL_1 Where CUSTOMER_NUMBER = 12345;
Select ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_SURNAME From A_TBL_2 Where ID IN (Select CUSTOMER_INFO_ID From A_TBL_1 Where CUSTOMER_NUMBER = 12345);
```

Here is the package for this

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE SCRIPTS AS 
    Procedure Init;
--
    FUNCTION split(csvString  IN  VarChar2, delimiter  IN  VarChar2 := ',') RETURN STRING_ARRAY;
--
    Function Get_Scripts(p_tab_1 VarChar2, p_key_col VarChar2, p_key_value Number, p_what VarChar2 := 'INSERT') RETURN VARCHAR2;
--
    Function Get_Link(p_tab_1 VarChar2) RETURN VARCHAR2;
--
    Function Get_Insert(p_pk_sql VarChar2, p_fk_sql VarChar2) RETURN VARCHAR2;
--
END SCRIPTS;
```

... and package body ...

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE BODY SCRIPTS AS

  m_fk_select      VarChar2(2000) := '';
  m_pk_select      VarChar2(2000) := '';
  m_where       VarChar2(512) := '';
  m_fk_cols        VarChar2(512) := '';
  m_fk_types       VarChar2(512) := '';
  m_pk_cols        VarChar2(512) := '';
  m_pk_types       VarChar2(512) := '';
  m_pk_vals        VarChar2(2000) := '';
  m_fk_vals        VarChar2(2000) := '';
  m_val         VarChar2(512) := '';
  m_tab_1       VarChar2(64) := '';
  m_tab_2       VarChar2(64) := '';
  --
  m_link_col    VarChar2(64) := '';
  m_key_col     VarChar2(64) := '';
  m_key_val     Number := 0;
  --
  m_selects     VarChar2(4000) := '';
  m_insert     VarChar2(2000) := '';
  m_pk_inserts     VarChar2(32000) := '';
  m_fk_inserts     VarChar2(32000) := '';
  --
  m_fk_tab    VarChar2(64) := '';
  m_fk_col    VarChar2(64) := '';  
  m_pk_tab    VarChar2(64) := '';
  m_pk_col    VarChar2(64) := '';
--  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE Init IS
BEGIN
  m_fk_select  := '';
  m_pk_select  := '';
  m_where   := '';
  m_fk_cols    := '';
  m_fk_types   := '';
  m_pk_cols    := '';
  m_pk_types   := '';
  m_pk_vals    := '';
  m_fk_vals    := '';
  m_val     := '';
  m_tab_1   := '';
  m_tab_2   := '';
  --
  m_link_col := '';
  m_key_col  := '';
  m_key_val  := 0;
  --
  m_selects  := '';
  m_insert   := '';
  m_pk_inserts  := '';
  m_fk_inserts  := '';
  --
  m_fk_tab   := '';
  m_fk_col   := '';  
  m_pk_tab   := '';
  m_pk_col   := '';
  --  ------------------------------------------------------
  
END Init;
--  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION split ( csvString  IN  VarChar2, delimiter  IN  VarChar2 := ',') RETURN STRING_ARRAY AS 
BEGIN
    Declare
        elements     STRING_ARRAY := STRING_ARRAY();
        CURSOR c IS
            SELECT  COL1
            FROM    (   SELECT INDX, MY_STR1, COL1_ELEMENTS, COL1
                  FROM  (   SELECT 0 "INDX", COL1 "MY_STR1", COL1_ELEMENTS, COL1
                          FROM(
                                SELECT
                                  REPLACE(COL1, delimiter || ' ', delimiter) "COL1",    
                                  Trim(Length(Replace(COL1, delimiter || ' ', delimiter))) - Trim(Length(Translate(REPLACE(COL1, delimiter || ' ', delimiter), 'A' || delimiter, 'A'))) + 1 "COL1_ELEMENTS"
                             --     Trim(Length(COL1)) - Trim(Length(Translate(COL1, 'A' || delimiter, 'A'))) + 1 "COL1_ELEMENTS"
                                FROM (SELECT csvString "COL1" FROM DUAL)        
                              )
                      )
                  MODEL     
                      DIMENSION BY(0 as INDX)
                      MEASURES(COL1, COL1_ELEMENTS, CAST('a' as VarChar2(4000)) as MY_STR1)
                      RULES ITERATE (1000)      --UNTIL (ITERATION_NUMBER <= COL1_ELEMENTS[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1]) -- If you don't know the number of elements this should be bigger then you aproximation. Othewrwise it will split given number of elements
                      (
                        COL1_ELEMENTS[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = COL1_ELEMENTS[0],
                        MY_STR1[0] = COL1[CV()],
                        MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = SubStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], InStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], delimiter, 1) + Length(delimiter)),
                        COL1[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = SubStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], 1, CASE WHEN InStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], delimiter) <> 0 THEN InStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], delimiter)-1 ELSE Length(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER]) END)
                      )
                )
            WHERE INDX > 0 And INDX <= COL1_ELEMENTS;  -- And COL1 Is Not Null;
        cStr    VarChar2(1000);
        i       Number := 1;
    Begin 
        If c%ISOPEN Then CLOSE c; End If;
        OPEN c;
        LOOP
            FETCH c Into cStr;
            EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
            elements.extend;
            elements(i) := cStr;
            i := i + 1;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c;
        RETURN elements;
    End;
END split;
--  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Function Get_Scripts(p_tab_1 VarChar2, p_key_col VarChar2, p_key_value Number, p_what VarChar2 := 'INSERT') RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  BEGIN
      Declare
          --    
          CURSOR c_fk_col IS
              Select  tc.TABLE_NAME, tc.COLUMN_ID, tc.COLUMN_NAME, tc.DATA_TYPE
              From    sys.all_tab_columns tc 
              Where   tc.TABLE_NAME = m_fk_tab
              Order By tc.COLUMN_ID;
          fk_col_Set    c_fk_col%ROWTYPE;
          --    
          CURSOR c_pk_col IS
              Select  tc.TABLE_NAME, tc.COLUMN_ID, tc.COLUMN_NAME, tc.DATA_TYPE
              From    sys.all_tab_columns tc 
              Where   tc.TABLE_NAME = m_pk_tab
              Order By tc.COLUMN_ID;
          pk_col_Set    c_pk_col%ROWTYPE;
          --
          m_return      VarChar2(2000) := '';
          m_status      VarChar2(64) := '';
          sq            varChar2(1) := '''';
          m_cmd         VarChar2(512) := '';
          m_fk_cols_count  Number(6) := 0;
          m_pk_cols_count  Number(6) := 0;
          m_pk_sql      VarChar2(1000) := '';
          m_fk_sql      VarChar2(1000) := '';
      Begin
          Init;
          m_status := Get_Link(p_tab_1);
          If SubStr(m_status, 1, 2) != 'OK' Then
              RETURN m_status;
          End If;
          --  ----------------------  FK TABLE  -----------------------------------------------------
          OPEN c_fk_col;
          LOOP
              FETCH c_fk_col Into fk_col_Set;
              EXIT WHEN c_fk_col%NOTFOUND;
              m_fk_cols_count := c_fk_col%ROWCOUNT;
              m_fk_cols := m_fk_cols || fk_col_Set.COLUMN_NAME || ', ';
              m_fk_types := m_fk_types || fk_col_Set.DATA_TYPE || ', ';
          END LOOP;
          CLOSE c_fk_col;
          --  -------------------------------
          m_fk_cols := SubStr(m_fk_cols, 1, Length(m_fk_cols) - 2);
          m_fk_types := SubStr(m_fk_types, 1, Length(m_fk_types) - 2);
          --
          m_where := ' Where ' || p_key_col || ' = ' || p_key_value;
          m_fk_select := 'Select ' || m_fk_cols || ' From ' || m_fk_tab || m_where || ';' || Chr(10); 
          m_selects := m_selects || m_fk_select;
          --  ----------------------- END FK TABLE ---------------------------------------------------
          --
          --  ----------------------  PK TABLE  -----------------------------------------------------
          OPEN c_pk_col;
          LOOP
              FETCH c_pk_col Into pk_col_Set;
              EXIT WHEN c_pk_col%NOTFOUND;
              m_pk_cols_count := c_pk_col%ROWCOUNT;
              m_pk_cols := m_pk_cols || pk_col_Set.COLUMN_NAME || ', ';
              m_pk_types := m_pk_types || pk_col_Set.DATA_TYPE || ', ';
          END LOOP;
          CLOSE c_pk_col;
          --  -------------------------------
          m_pk_cols := SubStr(m_pk_cols, 1, Length(m_pk_cols) - 2);
          m_pk_types := SubStr(m_pk_types, 1, Length(m_pk_types) - 2);
          --
          m_where := ' Where ' || m_pk_col || ' IN (Select ' || m_fk_col || ' From ' || m_fk_tab || ' Where ' || p_key_col || ' = ' || p_key_value || ')';
          m_pk_select := 'Select ' || m_pk_cols || ' From ' || m_pk_tab || m_where || ';' || Chr(10); 
          m_selects := m_selects || m_pk_select;
          --  ----------------------- END PK TABLE ---------------------------------------------------
          --
          If Upper(p_what) = 'SELECT' Then      -- If it is asked for 'SELECT' statements - RETURN
              m_return := m_selects;
              GoTo send_it;
          End If;
          --
          --  ----------------------- I n s e r t s -----------------------------------------------
          --
          m_status := 'ERR';
          m_pk_sql := 'Select ' || m_pk_cols || ', ROWNUM RN From ' || m_pk_tab || ' Where ' || m_pk_col || ' IN (Select ' || m_fk_col || ' From ' || m_fk_tab || ' Where ' || p_key_col || ' = ' || p_key_value || ')';
          m_fk_sql := 'Select ' || m_fk_cols || ', ROWNUM RN From ' || m_fk_tab || ' Where ' || p_key_col || ' = ' || p_key_value;
          m_status := Get_Insert(m_pk_sql, m_fk_sql);
          If SubStr(m_status, 1, 2) != 'OK' Then
              RETURN m_status;
          End If;

          If p_what = 'INSERT' Then
              m_return := m_pk_inserts || m_fk_inserts;
          Else
              m_return := m_selects;
          End If;
        <<send_it>>
          RETURN m_return;
        <<end_it>>
          Null;
      End;
  END Get_Scripts;
--  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Function Get_Link(p_tab_1 VarChar2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  BEGIN
      Declare
          m_return        VarChar2(255) := 'ERR - NO_LINK_FOUND';
      Begin
          SELECT  a.TABLE_NAME "FK_TAB_NAME", a.column_name "FK_COL_NAME", --a.CONSTRAINT_NAME "FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME", 
                  c_pk.TABLE_NAME "PK_TAB_NAME", --c_pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME "PK_CONST_NAME",
                  (Select COLUMN_NAME From all_cons_columns where TABLE_NAME = c_pk.TABLE_NAME And CONSTRAINT_NAME = c_pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME) "PK_COL_NAME"
          INTO    m_fk_tab, m_fk_col, m_pk_tab, m_pk_col
          FROM    all_cons_columns a
          INNER JOIN    all_constraints c     ON (a.OWNER = c.OWNER And a.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.CONSTRAINT_NAME)
          INNER JOIN    all_constraints c_pk  ON (c.r_owner = c_pk.OWNER And c.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = c_pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME)
          WHERE   c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' And 
                  a.TABLE_NAME = 'A_TBL_1' And 
                  EXISTS(Select * From all_cons_columns where TABLE_NAME = 'A_TBL_1');
          
          RETURN 'OK';
        <<end_it>>
            Null;
      Exception
          When NO_DATA_FOUND Then RETURN m_return;
      End;
  END Get_Link;
--  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Get_Insert(p_pk_sql VarChar2, p_fk_sql VarChar2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
  BEGIN
      Declare
          m_return      VarChar2(255) := 'ERR';
          m_cmd         VarChar(1000) := '';
          m_pk_count       Number(6) := 0;
          m_fk_count       Number(6) := 0;
          m_cols        Number(6) := 0;
          m_colnum      Number(6) := 0;
          m_type        VarChar2(64) := '';
          m_col         VarChar2(64) := '';
          sq            VarChar2(1) := '''';
      Begin
          --
          --  ------------------------------------- PK INSERT ------------------------------------------------------------------
          Select Count(*) into m_cols From TABLE(split(m_pk_cols));
          m_cmd := 'Select Count(*) From (' || Replace(Replace(p_pk_sql, Chr(10), ''), ';', '') || ')';
          execute immediate m_cmd Into m_pk_count;
          If m_pk_count = 0 Then
              GoTo send_it;
          End If;
          --  --------------------------------------
          m_pk_vals := '';
          m_val := '';

          For i In 1..m_pk_count Loop
              Begin
                  For j In 1..m_cols Loop
                      m_val := '';
                      m_cmd := 'Select COLUMN_VALUE, RN From (Select COLUMN_VALUE, ROWNUM RN From TABLE(split(' || sq || m_pk_cols || sq || ')) ) Where RN = ' || j;
                      execute immediate m_cmd Into m_col, m_colnum;
                      
                      m_cmd := 'Select COLUMN_VALUE, RN From (Select COLUMN_VALUE, ROWNUM RN From TABLE(split(' || sq || m_pk_types || sq || ')) ) Where RN = ' || j;
                      execute immediate m_cmd Into m_type, m_colnum;
                      
                      m_cmd := 'Select ' || m_col || ' From (' || p_pk_sql || ') Where RN = ' || i;
                      execute immediate m_cmd Into m_val;

                      If m_type = 'NUMBER' Then
                          m_pk_vals := m_pk_vals || m_val || ', ';
                      Else
                          m_pk_vals := m_pk_vals || sq || m_val || sq || ', ';
                      End If;
                  End Loop;
                  m_pk_vals := SubStr(m_pk_vals, 1, Length(m_pk_vals) - 2);
                  m_insert := 'INSERT INTO ' || m_pk_tab || ' (' || m_pk_cols || ') VALUES(' || m_pk_vals || ');';
              Exception When NO_DATA_FOUND Then Null;
              End;
              m_pk_inserts := m_pk_inserts || m_insert || Chr(10);
              m_insert := '';
              m_pk_vals := '';
              
          End Loop;
          
          --  ------------------------------------------- END PK INSERT -----------------------------------------------------------------
          --
          --  ------------------------------------- FK INSERT ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Select Count(*) into m_cols From TABLE(split(m_fk_cols));
          m_cmd := 'Select Count(*) From (' || Replace(Replace(p_fk_sql, Chr(10), ''), ';', '') || ')';
          execute immediate m_cmd Into m_fk_count;
          If m_fk_count = 0 Then
              GoTo send_it;
          End If;
          --  --------------------------------------
          m_fk_vals := '';
          m_val := '';
          For k In 1..m_fk_count Loop
              Begin
                  For l In 1..m_cols Loop
                      m_val := '';
                      m_cmd := 'Select COLUMN_VALUE, RN From (Select COLUMN_VALUE, ROWNUM RN From TABLE(split(' || sq || m_fk_cols || sq || ')) ) Where RN = ' || l;
                      execute immediate m_cmd Into m_col, m_colnum;
                      
                      m_cmd := 'Select COLUMN_VALUE, RN From (Select COLUMN_VALUE, ROWNUM RN From TABLE(split(' || sq || m_fk_types || sq || ')) ) Where RN = ' || l;
                      execute immediate m_cmd Into m_type, m_colnum;
                      
                      m_cmd := 'Select ' || m_col || ' From (' || p_fk_sql || ') Where RN = ' || k;
                      execute immediate m_cmd Into m_val;

                      If m_type = 'NUMBER' Then
                          m_fk_vals := m_fk_vals || m_val || ', ';
                      Else
                          m_fk_vals := m_fk_vals || sq || m_val || sq || ', ';
                      End If;
                  End Loop;
                  m_fk_vals := SubStr(m_fk_vals, 1, Length(m_fk_vals) - 2);
                  m_insert := 'INSERT INTO ' || m_fk_tab || ' (' || m_fk_cols || ') VALUES(' || m_fk_vals || ');';
              Exception When NO_DATA_FOUND Then Null;
              End;
              m_fk_inserts := m_fk_inserts || m_insert || Chr(10);
              m_insert := '';
              m_fk_vals := '';
          End Loop;
          --  ------------------------------------------- END FK INSERT ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          --
          m_return := 'OK';
        <<send_it>>
          RETURN m_return;      
        <<end_it>>
          Null;
      End;
  
  END Get_Insert;
END SCRIPTS;
```

... and user defined type

```sql
create or replace TYPE STRING_ARRAY AS  
VARRAY(4000) OF VARCHAR2(1000);
```

The package now handles different names of related columns and multiple rows of related data in any or both tables...

Sample 2
.... with some more combined data in starting table A_TBL_1 (INSERT)

```sql
        ID CUSTOMER_NUMBER CUSTOMER_INFO_ID
---------- --------------- ----------------
         1           12345              111 
         2           12345              111 
         3           45678              111 
         4           12345              222

INSERT INTO A_TBL_2 (ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_SURNAME) VALUES(111, 'NAME 1', 'SURNAME 1');
INSERT INTO A_TBL_2 (ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_SURNAME) VALUES(222, 'NAME 2', 'SURNAME 2');
INSERT INTO A_TBL_1 (ID, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_INFO_ID) VALUES(1, 12345, 111);
INSERT INTO A_TBL_1 (ID, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_INFO_ID) VALUES(2, 12345, 111);
INSERT INTO A_TBL_1 (ID, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_INFO_ID) VALUES(4, 12345, 222);
```